# What is the set $\{A \,\,\mid \text{ any two eigenvectors of }$A$\text{from different eigenspaces are orthogonal.}\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

I am reading "Masahiko Saito's Linear Algebra" (in Japanese) by Masahiko Saito.

The following three propositions are in this book.

> Let $A$ be a unitary matrix. Then, any two eigenvectors of $A$ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal.

> Let $A$ be an Hermitian matrix. Then, any two eigenvectors of $A$ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal.

> Let $A$ be a skew-Hermitian matrix. Then, any two eigenvectors of $A$ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal.

What is the set $\{A \,\,\mid \text{ any two eigenvectors of } A \text{ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal }\}$?

Is there a matrix $A\in\{A \,\mid \text{ any two eigenvectors of } A \text{ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal }\}$ which is not a normal matrix?
If so, please give me an example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: @user8268 Thank you very much for your link.

Comment: The set of **diagonalizable** matrices with this property is, by the spectral theorem, precisely the set of normal matrices. If we allow for non-diagonalizable $A$, then this gets a bit trickier.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Is there a matrix $A\in\{A \,\mid \text{ any two eigenvectors of } A \text{ from different eigenspaces are orthogonal }\}$ which is not a normal matrix?

Comment: A [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) would be an example for such a matrix.

Comment: @Hyperplane Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hyperplane, Thank you very much for your answer.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $AA^{*}=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $A^{*}A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.
So, ***$A$ is not a normal matrix.***
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $0$.
The eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $1$ is $\operatorname{Nul}\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\Biggr\{\alpha\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} \mid\alpha\in\mathbb{C}\Biggl\}$.
The eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $0$ is $\operatorname{Nul}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=\Biggr\{\beta\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix} \mid\beta\in\mathbb{C}\Biggl\}$.
So, any two eigenvectors of $A$ from different eigenspaces are ***orthogonal***.

Comment: This example works! Another example of a matrix which is not normal but all eigenvectors not in the same eigenspace are orthogonal is $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Note that this matrix is also invertible!

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Thank you very much for your example.